# File contents not filled in time to read from in C

Tags: c, file-io

The title is my best guess at the problem at the moment, but I'm not completely sure.
I'm trying to read from a file that contains numbers and strings that start with a character(only strings start with a char). This file is created earlier in the program by code that should execute before this file is needed.

main

```
int main(void){

//name of the file to accessed
char *fileName = "input.txt";
node *head, *tail;
node *symListHead = NULL;

head = tail = createNode();

//creates the file with no comments exits if the file is not created
if(cleanFile(fileName) == 0){
    exit(1);
}

//create the head of the linked list containing all tokens
head = createSymbolList();

//this should create the file and fill in called "lexemelist.txt"
printTableAndList( head );


//create a sym list of ints for comparison to enumerated types
symListHead = generateSymList();


//recursiveParse( symListHead );


return 0;

}//end main
```

So on the line with printTabelAndList(head) the file "lexemelist.txt" should be created and filled. And in symListHead = generateSymList() that file should be used. But if I run the code with symListHead = generateSymList() commented out the file is created and filled as it should be, but if the line is left in the file is left empty leading and nothing is read from the empty file.

lexemelist.txt contents with the line symListHead = generateSymList(); left in

```
29  2 x 17  2 y 18 21  2 x 20  2 y 4  3 56 18 22 19
```

lexemelist.txt contents with the line symListHead = generateSymList(); removed

genetateSymList()

```
symNode *generateSymList(){

FILE *fp;
char buff[255];
symNode *head, *temp;

head = temp = createSymNode();

fp = fopen("lexemelist.txt" , "r");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("\nfile not found.\n");
    return NULL;
    }
//this line is skicped since the file is empty for some reason
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buff) != EOF)
{
    if(isalpha(buff[0]))
        continue;

    printf("%d", atoi(buff));
    temp->sym = atoi(buff);
    temp->next = createSymNode();

    temp = temp->next;

}//end while

fclose(fp);

return head;
}
```

printTableAndList()

```
void printTableAndList(node *head){

FILE *tfp, *lfp;
tfp = fopen("lexemetable.txt", "w");
lfp = fopen("lexemelist.txt", "w");
fprintf(tfp , "lexeme         token type\n\n");

    generateTableAndList(head, tfp, lfp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I forgot to close my files in the printTableAndList() function.